# Play a audio file through multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm making a game using a HTML and CSS because I'm still a beginner. The game is a choice based story game where you choose to what you want to do. So I use multiple HTML and CSS files to do this. But I ran into a problem when I tried to add a music to the game. The problem is that if I do the `<audio>` tag then the music will start the beginning. I need a way to store the data of the audio file then load it to another HTML file. If anyone has a solution to the audio let me know

Comment: You could use an `iframe` to make sure that the audio frame _stays_ loaded and playing while the other frame's content changes to a new HTML page

Comment: when changing pages the audio will be interrupted (you could store the current time and pass to the next page and pick up from there in the audio player). Best solution is either make the game a single web page, or host the game inside an iframe and play the audio from the host page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It just a simply html file and css file.

Answer (score 0):

do not place your game directly inside main body of html page, but instead create an `<iframe>` element that will include your gameplay html as source for this iframe `<iframe src=xxxx>`. Place  inside your main html page.

Now: contents of `<iframe>` element might be changing but this will not affect `<audio>` or other elements (like main menu etc.) that will be outside this iframe.

Comment: but how do I store the audio data so I can play it in another html file.